# Display data in combobox from one winform to another winform

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, combobox, vb.net-2010

I have this form1 that displays a list of my entries. When I want to update an entry, I will click it in the DataGridView and an update button will be visible. Once I clicked the 'Update' button, form2 will appear and the details of the currently selected row in my dgv will be listed.

My problem is that one of the details involves a data from a combobox. It does not change the value.

This form2 acts as a form to create entries and at the same time to update them. I load the details to this form as is like you are creating one but I am updating them.

Now this combobox has data that has been loaded from the database. Something like this:

```
        Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand
        Dim dt2 As New DataTable

        con.Open()

        With cmd2
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "Select staff_name from staff where staff_position='Pre-seller'"

        End With

        da.SelectCommand = cmd2
        da.Fill(dt2)
        With cmbseller
            .DataSource = dt2
            .DisplayMember = "staff_name"
            .ValueMember = "staff_name"

        End With
        con.Close()
```

All is well, until I need to update an entry. The data in the combo box is not changing from the details of my currently selected row.

For example, the data in the entry for this combobox is 'Leizel', but when I click the update to show form2, it shows a different item. Like the one that has been loaded from the database. It is not adjusting to what I want. I change the other details but not this one.

Can anyone suggest anything?

---

EDIT:
This is the code I am using in loading data from form1 to form2. obviously this is only a part of it.

```
Dim frm3 As New SalesOrder
frm3.cmbseller.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value
```

where 2 is the column in my dgv that needs to be displayed in the combobox in form2.

Comment: Form2 needs to be populated using the values in Form1 directly, not called from the database. Can we see the code you're using to populate Form2?

Comment: Show code where or how you set `cmbseller.SelectedValue`. Obviously for creating a new item value should be some default value, but for updating value should be copied from Form1 or from database

Comment: Hi @MahendranNadesan , I updated my code. See above

Comment: Hi @Fabio Yes the values are from the database and displayed in a DGV. All other details are being copied into their respective fields except for the combo boxes, which the Items/collections are data from the database. The reason is I want to dynamically display data on those combo boxes.

Comment: I assume `DataGridView1` is from Form1? I'm just guessing here, but it might be that calling `.Value`, which has been set via the database is the issue - have you tried just getting the display value (maybe `.Text`). Alternatively, to test, assign the changed text to a variable, then assign that variable to `frm3.cmbseller.Text`

Comment: @MahendranNadesan Hi! Sorry took me long to response. I have tried what you've suggested but it still didn't work.

Comment: I think we're going to have to see more code. Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger? Your result suggests that at the time of binding, your value is/has reverted to the db value. Check that that is the case when debugging. What if you play around with the values without calling your form - I assume something like `frm3.cmbseller.Text = "my text"` works fine?